# Apple Watch activity too high

Tags: ios, health.app, health-kit, apple-watch

I have a new Apple Watch and have to learn how to use this device properly.

Because I miss-add a workout in the Health App my activity rings show that I exercised more than 1000 minutes.

[image]

I cannot find these minutes anymore kn my Health App but want to clean these results.

Comment: Did you find a fix for that ? my AW3 reports wild activity whiile doing nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to delete the data relating to this via the Health app on your iPhone.

More specifically:

1. On your iPhone open the Health app
2. Tap on the Sources icon at bottom
3. At the bottom of the Sources screen you'll see a list of your devices - one of them will be for your Apple Watch. Tap on this.
4. Now you'll see a range of options - tap on the one that says Exercise Minutes
5. Now you'll see a screen that lists all recorded data, sorted with most recent at top
6. Identify the one(s) you need to delete
7. Now tap on the red Edit option at top right
8. Now you can delete any of the entries you want to (**NOTE:** Be careful **not** to tap on the Delete All option at top left!)

Comment: My number of exercise minutes are not listed there. Maybe I removed them already. Can I force my Apple Watch to re-synchronize?

Comment: If you're looking for a large figure of minutes you probably won't see that. In my case it's all in 1 min intervals, so you may need to identify the timeframe and delete all of them individually.

Comment: Hang on, I just realised in your question you also referred to a workout, so maybe at so maybe at Step 4 instead of tapping on *Exercise Minutes* you should try tapping on *Workouts*. Does that show you what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, the other data I already found and deleted was associated to my smartphone and not my apple watch.

Comment: Ah, okay, you may need to also check the order of your data sources for your Activity. In the Health app, tap on the Health Data icon at bottom and then on the Activity square at top left. Now swipe up and see if you can find a value that correlates with your 1000+ mins. If so, tap on it and then swipe up and tap on the Data Sources & Access option. You'll see your data sources listed - make sure your Apple Watch is listed first so that's the one it's reading data from.

Comment: If none of this helps, you may be able to just go into the Activity app on your iPhone instead. Then tap on the Workouts icon at bottom. In the Workouts screen tap on November at top to see a list of all workouts for November. If you see one that correlates with your 1000+ mins, then you can swipe left on that to delete it.

Comment: There is no workout (anymore?) associated with the 1000 minutes. I can see my Apple Watch as a source only but I can not modify anything here.
Can I re-synchronize it or remove all activity data?